# Next.js / React single page app needs urls for each item

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes

I've build a single page application in Next JS + React JS + Tailwind where I load a number of items from firebase. 
I use Firebase's docRef as an ID in the application.
Now I want users to be able to reference an item from the URL and share it with others. How would I go about implementing that? 
I've looked into Next.js Routing / Dynamic routing and React router, however since it's my first time using React and Next.js I don't know where to start. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: you have an overview page and detail pages. In routing terms, this would look like: */overview* and */overview/${ID}*

You should take a look at https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation. In more detail:

```
// pages/posts/[id].js

function Post({ post }) {
  // Render post...
}

// This function gets called at build time
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.id },
  }))

  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
  return { paths, fallback: false }
}

// This also gets called at build time
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // params contains the post `id`.
  // If the route is like /posts/1, then params.id is 1
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../posts/${params.id}`)
  const post = await res.json()

  // Pass post data to the page via props
  return { props: { post } }
}

export default Post
```

Inside getStaticPaths, you define what dynamic paths are available. Next.js will generate these pages. Inside getStaticProps, you pass in the object you return from getStaticPaths. Inside the return of this function, you pass all the info/props you need to build the detail page.